# Use XML stored in a resource file as mock data for unit tests

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing

I'm trying to use some XML data stored in a .resx file as test data for unit tests.

I have this code that takes the test data, converts it to a stream, and tries to deserialize it into a collection of Students that I can use with my mock dbset.

```
var stream = TestData.Students.ToStream();
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Collection<Student>));
_students = (Collection<Student>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Student class

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public char MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

It fails on the last line with this exception:

```
{"<Students xmlns=''> was not expected."}
```

I've tried adding the Serializable attribute to the Student class, tried adding the XMLRoot attribute to it, also searched around on Google for a while, but couldn't really find anything dealing with resource files.

On a side note, is there an easier/better method for getting test data?

**Edit**
If it helps I'm following [this](http://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/the-fastest-way-to-mock-a-database-for-unit-testing-B6) article.

**Edit 2**
So drilling down into the stack trace of the inner exception, I found this line:

```
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderCollection1.Read4_ArrayOfStudent()
```

So I changed the root element of the XML from Students to ArrayOfStudent and voila, it correctly deserializes.

Here's my XML data in the resource file.

```
<Students>
  <Student>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <LastName>Alexander</LastName>
    <FirstName>Carson</FirstName>
    <EnrollmentDate>2010-09-01T00:00:00</EnrollmentDate>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <LastName>Alonso</LastName>
    <FirstName>Meredith</FirstName>
    <EnrollmentDate>2012-09-01T00:00:00</EnrollmentDate>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <LastName>Anand</LastName>
    <FirstName>Arturo</FirstName>
    <EnrollmentDate>2013-09-01T00:00:00</EnrollmentDate>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Id>4</Id>
    <LastName>Barzdukas</LastName>
    <FirstName>Gytis</FirstName>
    <EnrollmentDate>2012-09-01T00:00:00</EnrollmentDate>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Id>5</Id>
    <LastName>Li</LastName>
    <FirstName>Yan</FirstName>
    <EnrollmentDate>2012-09-01T00:00:00</EnrollmentDate>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Id>6</Id>
    <LastName>Justice</LastName>
    <FirstName>Peggy</FirstName>
    <EnrollmentDate>2011-09-01T00:00:00</EnrollmentDate>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Id>7</Id>
    <LastName>Norman</LastName>
    <FirstName>Laura</FirstName>
    <EnrollmentDate>2013-09-01T00:00:00</EnrollmentDate>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Id>8</Id>
    <LastName>Olivetto</LastName>
    <FirstName>Nino</FirstName>
    <EnrollmentDate>2005-08-11T00:00:00</EnrollmentDate>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Id>9</Id>
    <LastName>Alexander</LastName>
    <FirstName>Carson</FirstName>
    <EnrollmentDate>2010-09-01T00:00:00</EnrollmentDate>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Id>10</Id>
    <LastName>Alonso</LastName>
    <FirstName>Meredith</FirstName>
    <EnrollmentDate>2012-09-01T00:00:00</EnrollmentDate>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Id>11</Id>
    <LastName>Anand</LastName>
    <FirstName>Arturo</FirstName>
    <EnrollmentDate>2013-09-01T00:00:00</EnrollmentDate>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Id>12</Id>
    <LastName>Barzdukas</LastName>
    <FirstName>Gytis</FirstName>
    <EnrollmentDate>2012-09-01T00:00:00</EnrollmentDate>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Id>13</Id>
    <LastName>Li</LastName>
    <FirstName>Yan</FirstName>
    <EnrollmentDate>2012-09-01T00:00:00</EnrollmentDate>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Id>14</Id>
    <LastName>Justice</LastName>
    <FirstName>Peggy</FirstName>
    <EnrollmentDate>2011-09-01T00:00:00</EnrollmentDate>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Id>15</Id>
    <LastName>Norman</LastName>
    <FirstName>Laura</FirstName>
    <EnrollmentDate>2013-09-01T00:00:00</EnrollmentDate>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Id>16</Id>
    <LastName>Olivetto</LastName>
    <FirstName>Nino</FirstName>
    <EnrollmentDate>2005-08-11T00:00:00</EnrollmentDate>
  </Student>
</Students>
```

Comment: You need a class `<Students>` to hold the `Student` list, or you have to apply the proper attributes. Try searching.

Comment: @CodeCaster Can I not just store the list in a variable? And I have searched. I wasn't able to find anything, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: I mean search on what I said. Please show your class in your question.

Comment: @CodeCaster I figured it out, see edit 2, but its weird, haha

Comment: Feel free to self-answer with that. Show the class definition in your question or answer, of both `ArrayOfStudent` and `Student`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out when deserializing, the serializer was looking for a root element of ArrayOf{ClassName}, so changing the root element Students to ArrayOfStudent did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you can get data from xml file using this code

```
using (FileStream sr = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Students));
                    return serializer.Deserialize(sr) as Students;
                }
```

For *Xmlns* you can't use attribute, to add namespaces you should add

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces np = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
```

and then add new namespaces to **np** , add this **np** to serialize or Deserialize as parameter

Comment: It's not an xml file, it's just xml text in a .resx file

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (adding a root element for your partial xml)

```
var xmlString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\YourDirectory\Students.xml");

var rootAttribute = new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = "Students", IsNullable = true };
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Student[]), rootAttribute);
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
Student[] students = (Student[])serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

I'm just reading the whole text from file here, you can use a stream, won't matter.